# Using localStorage to remember closed state of pop-up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulty implementing localStorage on my site (https://www.reclaimdesign.org).

What I am trying to do is:

- Newsletter subscription pop-up on each page - this works fine
- Click X to close the subscription pop-up - this also works fine
- Remember the closed state of the window so that all other pages visited on our site don't have the pop-up and irritate the user after they have closed the pop-up already - this is not working. Not even a little bit.

My thinking was to set a variable with localStorage and then refer to the variable to see if the windows should be displayed or not. It is highly likely that my logic and syntax are at best sketchy, so if anyone could please guide me in the correct method this would be much appreciated.

The code I have been tinkering with for the subscription pop-up looks like this:

```
<script>
function setSignup(val) {
localStorage.setItem("popState", val); 
}

function getSignup() {
$(window).on("load", function() {   
    if(localStorage.getItem("popState") == 'hide'){
        //$(".signup").hide();
        $(".signup").css("display", "none");
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem("popState") != 'hide'){
        $(".signup").css("display", "block");
    }
});
}
</script>

<div class="signup">
<div class="signup-header">Sustainable Living</div>
<span class="closebtn" onclick="setSignup('hide');this.parentElement.style.display='none';">×</span>
<div class="signup-container">
<p>Get new articles related to <em>sustainability</em> and <em>eco-friendly home decor</em> direct to your inbox. We respect your privacy.</p>
<form action="https://reclaimdesign.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0c1d87de694b90628655f4ab9&amp;id=bab84d57de" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" rel="noopener" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required autocomplete="email">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0c1d87de694b90628655f4ab9_bab84d57de" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When is getSignup() function called? i don't think it is called anywhere. You do no need that function wrapper, just window onload....

Answer (score 0):

Yes your getSignup is not called correctly. 
Here you can see the alternative solution without jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function setSignup(val) {
      localStorage.setItem("popState", val);
    }

    function getSignup() {
      if (localStorage.getItem("popState") == 'hide') {
        //$(".signup").hide();
        document.querySelector('.signup').style.display = 'none';
      } else if (localStorage.getItem("popState") != 'hide') {
        document.querySelector('.signup').style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", getSignup);
  </script>

  <div class="signup">
    <div class="signup-header">Sustainable Living</div>
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="setSignup('hide');this.parentElement.style.display='none';">×</span>
    <div class="signup-container">
      <p>Get new articles related to <em>sustainability</em> and <em>eco-friendly home decor</em> direct to your inbox. We respect your privacy.</p>
      <form action="https://reclaimdesign.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0c1d87de694b90628655f4ab9&amp;id=bab84d57de" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" rel="noopener" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          <div class="mc-field-group">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required autocomplete="email">
          </div>
          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0c1d87de694b90628655f4ab9_bab84d57de" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
          <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your input guys. I got it working with the following (for anyone who might come up against the same issue)...

HTML:

```
<div class="signup">
<div class="signup-header">Sustainable Living</div>
<div class="signup-container">
<p>Get new articles related to <em>sustainability</em> and <em>eco-friendly home decor</em> direct to your inbox. We respect your privacy.</p>
<form action="https://reclaimdesign.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0c1d87de694b90628655f4ab9&amp;id=bab84d57de" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" rel="noopener" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required autocomplete="email">
 </div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0c1d87de694b90628655f4ab9_bab84d57de" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .signup {
    bottom: 2%;
    display: none;
    margin-right: -15px !important;
    max-width: 280px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 2%;  
    z-index: 9999;  
}

.signup-header {
    background: #539c22;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Carrois Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.signup-container {
    background-color: #6db240;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}

.closebtn {
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 15px;
    top: 5px;   
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: #6db240;
}

.signup-container .button {
    background-color: #539c22; 
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.23s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.signup-container .button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.signup-container .mc-field-group input {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-indent: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.signup-container input {
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: auto;
    font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.signup').css('display', 'block');

    $PopUp = $('.signup');

    var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));

    if (hide) {
        $PopUp.hide();
    } else {
        // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
        localStorage.setItem('hide', false);
    }

    $('.closebtn').click(function() {
        $('.signup' ).hide();
        // toggle the boolean by negating its value
        var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));
        localStorage.setItem('hide', !hide);
    });
});
```